# Statistic float addition using 'delegate float'

Tags: c#, delegates

I am constructing a statistic system. In the system are certain stats that rely on other stats to calculate their final value. Here is my original attempt at this:

```
public class ModdedStat
{
    public delegate float Mod();
    public Mod mod;
    public float baseStat;
    public float finalStat
    {
        get
        {
            return baseStat + mod();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is return baseStat + the last listener subscribed to mod. I tested this as follows:

```
stat.baseStat = 0;
stat.mod += Out1;
stat.mod += Out2;
Console.Write(stat.finalStat);
```

Out1 and Out2 are functions that return 1 and 2 respectively. The console write returned '2'.

I have never used return type delegates before, so im not sure what is wrong with my logic. Is there a solution similar to this, or even just completely different workaround?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because by default, calling a multicast will run all the delegates you added using `+=`, but the return value returned will be the one from the last one you added. After all, one call can only return one value.

if you want the output `3`, you can use [`GetInvocationList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.getinvocationlist?view=netcore-3.1) to get the delegates that you added using `+=` to the multicast delegate. You can then loop through the array and add the return values up.

```
public float finalStat
{
    get
    {
        float totalMod = 0;
        foreach(Mod m in mod.GetInvocationList()) {
            totalMod += m();
        }
        return baseStat + totalMod;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're amazing! Thanks so much for the quick result :) Marking as answered

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `delegate` with `GetInvocationList` for this scenario would be `Func`:

```
var funcs = new List<Func<int>>();
funcs.Add(Out1);
funcs.Add(Out2);

funcs.Sum(f => f());
```

Or using your class:

```
public class ModdedStat
{
    readonly List<Func<int>> funcs = new List<Func<int>>();

    public void AddFunc(Func<int>)
    {
        funcs.Add(func);
    }

    public float baseStat;
    public float finalStat => baseStat + funcs.Sum(f => f());
}
```

Then:

```
stat.baseStat = 0;
stat.AddFunc(Out1);
stat.AddFunc(Out2);
Console.Write(stat.finalStat);
```